# Restricting movement to a specific section

Tags: simulation, experimental-design, one-simulator

I am currently trying to working with restricting the agents to on 1/4 of the whole Manhattan map. The idea is simple and as follows;
Let us say we have 10 agents, their names being v1, v2 ... v10. I want them to move only in a specific section. Currently the method in whcih the MapBasedMovement has been made is such that it moves in all the place, but I need it to move in only specified coordinates.

Thanks,

I tried picking a specific set of coordinates i.e. (0, 0) and (700, 700). Tried to find all the MapNode that are between them and then ask the DTNNode to select only the MapNode in these coordinates. But this does not give me the correct results.

Adding code below

```
    public Path getPath() {
    Path p = new Path(generateSpeed());
    MapNode curNode = lastMapNode;
    MapNode prevNode = lastMapNode;
    MapNode nextNode = null;    
    List<MapNode> neighbors;
    Coord nextCoord;
    
    assert lastMapNode != null: "Tried to get a path before placement";
    
    // start paths from current node 
    p.addWaypoint(curNode.getLocation());
    
    int pathLength = rng.nextInt(maxPathLength-minPathLength) + 
        minPathLength;

    for (int i=0; i<pathLength; i++) 
    {
    //          neighbors = curNode.getNeighbors();
        neighbors = host.possibleNodes;
        Vector<MapNode> n2 = new Vector<MapNode>(neighbors);
        if (!this.backAllowed) 
        {
            n2.remove(prevNode); // to prevent going back
        }   
            
        if (okMapNodeTypes != null) { //remove neighbor nodes that aren't ok
            for (int j=0; j < n2.size(); ){
                if (!n2.get(j).isType(okMapNodeTypes)) {
                    n2.remove(j);
                }
                else {
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
        
        if (n2.size() == 0) { // only option is to go back
            nextNode = prevNode;
        }
        else
        { 
           // choose a random node from remaining neighbors
           //nextNode = n2.get(rng.nextInt(n2.size()));
            nextNode = host.possibleNodes.get(rng.nextInt(host.possibleNodes.size()));
            System.out.println(lastMapNode);
            
            List<MapNode> nodePath = pathFinder.getShortestPath(lastMapNode, nextNode);
            


            
            for (MapNode node : nodePath) 
            { // create a Path from the shortest path
                p.addWaypoint(node.getLocation());
            }
            
            lastMapNode = nextNode;
            prevNode = curNode;
            nextCoord = nextNode.getLocation();
            curNode = nextNode;
            
            return p;
            
            
        }
        
        prevNode = curNode;
    
        nextCoord = nextNode.getLocation();
        curNode = nextNode;
        
        p.addWaypoint(nextCoord);
    }
    
    lastMapNode = curNode;

    return p;
}
```

Here, the parts where the host.possibleNodes have been mentioned are a method that I have made which basically tries to get the coordinates of each node and bins to a specific region. I can add that method as well if needed.

Comment: Thanks @pjs. Will change my question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you should be able to achieve this by using the [okMaps](https://github.com/akeranen/the-one/blob/master/src/movement/MapBasedMovement.java#L56) setting and dividing your map input file to segments accordingly.